# Symfony Base Controller vs. Before and After Filters

Tags: php, symfony, hook

I'm relatively new to Symfony (version 4) and have put together a REST API using the framework.

I have several controllers corresponding to endpoints many of which use common services. One service is common to every controller.

Currently I am injecting these services manually into each controller.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use App\Services\Utilities;
use App\Services\Database;
use App\Services\Session;
use App\Services\Rest;

class Fetch extends Controller {

    protected $API;
    protected $DB;
    protected $u;

    public function init() {

        $this->API = new Rest();
        $this->DB = new Database();
        $this->u = new Utilities();

        $this->API->init();
        $this->DB->init($this->DB->default_credentials); 

        // ....
```

Its kinda repetitive and not very efficient since each class needs to be instantiated every time an endpoint is requested.

There is a need for a global base controller.

Having browsed the Symfony docs & stackoverflow posts, it looks like I can create a base controller and have all my other controllers `extend` it like so:

```
class Fetch extends BaseController {
//.....
```

And all the methods in `BaseController` will be available in `Fetch`. Moreover, I can run hooks in `BaseController` that will run globally (as long as all my controllers extend `BaseController`.

I have also come upon [this symfony docs article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html) describing implementation of "Before and After Filters" that hook into all requests.

Which method (BaseController / Before and After Filters) would be best appropriate for what is effectively some code I want to run globally every time a request is made & why?

Comment: The before/after filters (per your link) are clearly the better solution but I don't see how to explain it without you spending more time reviewing the basics.  Your example of "injecting services" via your init method is just plain conceptually wrong for Symfony.  Maybe start with reading about [Symfony services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before and After should better then BaseController model, here is why:

suppose, you write 10 Controller class which extends BaseController class and BaseController class initiate 5 services. the possibility very high that every controller class may not require all 5 services. that will overhead for all 10 controller classes.

So, if you implement Before/After filter, you define which controller is executing and initiate services which require for this controller.